# get url link from href by beautifulsoup without redirect link

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get just URL without redirect the link.
my code is:

```
html = '<a class="css-10y60kr" href="/biz_redir?url=https%3A%2F%2Faceplumbingandrooter.com&amp;cachebuster=1642876680&amp;website_link_type=website&amp;src_bizid=hqjCHBGnEj4nECnLJBvjQw&amp;s=2caa69aa7350cca9ad00f1fd1d5a6346f341dd43e1ede874aa2eaa94d6a3458f" rel="noopener nofollow" role="link" target="_blank">https://aceplumbingandrooter.c…</a>'

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```

in tag a `['href']` content :

```
href="/biz_redir?url=https%3A%2F%2Faceplumbingandrooter.com&amp;cachebuster=1642876680&amp;website_link_type=website&amp;src_bizid=hqjCHBGnEj4nECnLJBvjQw&amp;s=2caa69aa7350cca9ad00f1fd1d5a6346f341dd43e1ede874aa2eaa94d6a3458f"
```

I want just the link URL: `aceplumbingandrooter.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) package. The URL you are looking for is indeed one of the parameters of the `/biz_redir`, so we need to first get the `'url'` parameter out of it.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = '/biz_redir?url=https%3A%2F%2Faceplumbingandrooter.com&amp;' \
      'cachebuster=1642876680&amp;website_link_type=website&amp;' \
      'src_bizid=hqjCHBGnEj4nECnLJBvjQw&amp;s=2caa69aa7350cca9ad00' \
      'f1fd1d5a6346f341dd43e1ede874aa2eaa94d6a3458f'

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
print(parse_qs(parsed_url.query)['url'][0])
```

This gives you full URL `https://aceplumbingandrooter.com`. You can then parse it further and get the `netloc`, here is complete code:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = '/biz_redir?url=https%3A%2F%2Faceplumbingandrooter.com&amp;' \
      'cachebuster=1642876680&amp;website_link_type=website&amp;' \
      'src_bizid=hqjCHBGnEj4nECnLJBvjQw&amp;s=2caa69aa7350cca9ad00' \
      'f1fd1d5a6346f341dd43e1ede874aa2eaa94d6a3458f'

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
new = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)['url'][0]
new = urlparse(new)
print(new.netloc)
```

output:

```
aceplumbingandrooter.com
```